# What is difference between these Generic types

Tags: java, generics

I have two questions

1.Is there any difference between below two declarations.?
(case i)

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList();
```

(case ii)

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2.I know that generics  benefits is `Stronger type checks at compile time`.
Then why we need to declare like in  `case ii` ?
Since Object creation is at runtime only declaration at compile time.

Comment: Well the first generates a warning, for one thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference in the code that's *executed* - but the first form will generate a warning. 
If you don't have linting enabled for generics, you're likely to get a message like this:

```
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

With the suggested flag, you'll get something like this:

```
Test.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        List<String> li = new ArrayList();
                          ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    ArrayList
1 warning
```

The reason for the warning is that it's *sort of* not as safe - you're using an expression of a **raw type** (`new ArrayList()`) as the value to assign to a variable of type `List<String>`. The compiler doesn't know whether this raw type value was *actually* originally created to hold other vaues. For example:

```
List numbers = new ArrayList(); // Raw types on both sides
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(10));
List<String> li = numbers;
String first = li.get(0);
```

Or even:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Numbers>();
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(10));
List raw = numbers;
List<String> li = raw;
String first = li.get(0);
```

In both of these cases, we'll end up with an exception when we get to the last line... whereas if we were using the generic type for *all* expressions, it wouldn't even compile:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Numbers>();
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(10));
List<String> li = numbers; // Compile-time error
String first = li.get(0);
```

Raw types are only present for backward compatibility, and should be avoided wherever possible.

See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Raw%20Types) for more details.

Comment: Broken link at the end?

Comment: @Prabhaker: You should either get an actual warning, or an indication that you *would* get a warning with `-Xlint:unchecked`. I've edited my answer to indicate that.

Comment: yes you are right that I am getting warning(-Xlint:unchecked).@Jon Skeet Thank you very much for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No. The diamond syntax is merely a shorthand in coding/typing. These two are the same

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();  
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

They are treated the same for the compiling process, hints to the compiler. Even before type erasure, they are treated the same. It's literally just a convenience for you.

Answer (score 1):

The two *declarations* are identical: They are both:

```
List<String>
```

It's the two *assignments* that differ.

At runtime (due to type erasure) they are also identical, but at compile time you get a warning for the first one, because you're assigning a *raw* type to a typed variable.